# How can two forms on different threads access each other's controls

Tags: c#, winforms

I searched for a long time to find access methods from parent form to child or vice versa. But they don't work when my forms are on different threads. I need two forms not covering the other all the time so I create the child form on the other thread.
Here are my simplified codes. Anyway to modify them? Thanks in advance!

```
namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    public class FormA : Form
    {
        public static Thread th1;
        FormB FB = new FormB();

        public Button A1;
        public FormA()
        {
            A1 = new Button();
            A1.Click += new EventHandler(A1Click);
            this.Controls.Add(this.A1);

            Thread th1 = new Thread(this.OpenFormB);
            th1.Start();
        }
        void A1Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FB.B1Text("B1");
        }
        void OpenFormB()
        {
            FB.ShowDialog();    //FB.ShowDialog(this); reports cross-thread error
        }
        void A1Text(string text1)
        {
            if (this.A1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                Del1 STR1 = delegate { A1Text(text1); };
                this.Invoke(STR1, text1);
            }
            else
            {
                this.A1.Text = text1;
            }
        }
        delegate void Del1(string text1);

        public class FormB : Form
        {
            public Button B1;
            public FormB()
            {
                B1 = new Button();
                B1.Click += new EventHandler(B1Click);
                this.Controls.Add(this.B1);
            }
            void B1Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                FormA FA = (FormA)this.Owner;   //'Owner' is not passed here because of the cross-thread error so the next command fails
                FA.A1Text("A1");
            }
            public void B1Text(string text1)
            {
                if (this.B1.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    Del1 STR1 = delegate { B1Text(text1); };
                    this.Invoke(STR1, text1);
                }
                else
                {
                    this.B1.Text = text1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

correct my codes to realize my purpose

Comment: Everything you need to know is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls?view=netdesktop-7.0

Comment: `I need two forms not covering the other all the time so I create the child form on the other thread.` The solution to this is surely to create a non-modal dialog using `Form.Show()` ...

Comment: What is the point of trying to run a Form in a different Thread? What does *I need two forms not covering the other all the time* mean, in practice? Explain that more in depth -- There are no child Forms here, and Owner != Parent

Comment: @MatthewWatson@Jimi I have tried '.Show()' but one form is always in front of the other. Can the active form always on top? Right now I have no other reason to use multithreading forms.

Comment: When you use `Form.Show()` you should be able to click on either form and it will become active and in front of the other form. Are you saying that doesn't happen?

Comment: @MatthewWatson No, it doesn't. Taking the non-multithreading solution RedStoneMatt provided as example, FormB always lies in front of FormA.

Comment: The owner should be set to `null` not to another form. If you set the owner to another form, then the form will never be displayed behind its owner. See the documentation for [`Form.Owner`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.owner?view=windowsdesktop-7.0). That's why my original comment above said you should call `Form.Show()` (with NO parameter)

Comment: @MatthewWatson Then is there another way to access FormA from FormB if the handle is not passed through Form.Show()?

Comment: Sure, just pass a reference to `FormA` to the `FormB` constructor, or add a `SetFormA(FormA formA)` method to `FormB` so you can set it after both forms have been constructed.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Oh, yes! RedStoneMatt's solution has already given the answer. I just need to replace 'ShowDialog' with 'Show' and additional threads are no longer needed. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This answer is divided in two parts:

- **With multithreading:** I kept multithreading as it might be required for your project on a greater scale
- **Without multithreading:** Something very similar to what you asked for can be done without multithreading in the first place, avoiding cross-thread access exceptions.

### With multithreading

As you mentionned in your comment, `FB.ShowDialog(this);` does not work and causes a "Can't be accessed from another thread" error.

This is because, when passing Form A as the owner here, the `Owner` property of Form B gets changed in Form B's thread. But according to the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Form.cs,2156), changing this property calls `AddOwnedForm` on the new owner, which effectively means that a Form A method is called on Form B's thread.

An easy workaround is to have a Form A reference in Form B, and to pass it from Form A to Form B when constructing it.

Here is the code I came up with:

```
public partial class FormA : Form
{
    public static Thread th1;
    FormB FB = null;

    public Button A1;
    public FormA()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        A1 = new Button();
        A1.Click += new EventHandler(A1Click);
        this.Controls.Add(this.A1);

        FB = new FormB(this);

        Thread th1 = new Thread(this.OpenFormB);
        th1.Start();
    }

    void A1Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FB.B1Text("B1");
    }

    void OpenFormB()
    {
        FB.ShowDialog();
    }

    public void A1Text(string text1)
    {
        if (this.A1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            Del1 STR1 = delegate { A1Text(text1); };
            this.Invoke(STR1, text1);
        }
        else
        {
            this.A1.Text = text1;
        }
    }
    delegate void Del1(string text1);
}

public partial class FormB : Form
{
    public Button B1;
    
    FormA FA = null;

    public FormB(FormA owner)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        B1 = new Button();
        B1.Click += new EventHandler(B1Click);
        this.Controls.Add(this.B1);

        this.FA = owner;
    }

    void B1Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FA.A1Text("A1");
    }

    public void B1Text(string text1)
    {
        if (this.B1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            Del1 STR1 = delegate { B1Text(text1); };
            this.Invoke(STR1, text1);
        }
        else
        {
            this.B1.Text = text1;
        }
    }
    delegate void Del1(string text1);
}
```

Do note that this is pretty hacky, we effectively just create an alternate owner.

### Without multithreading

You don't need multithreading to have two forms existing at the same time.

The real problem here is that you use `FB.ShowDialog();` to show Form B.
However, as [the documentation for this method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) says, **when this method is called, the code following it is not executed until after the dialog box is closed.**

Which I suppose is why you wanted to have it on another thread, so it could run along with Form A.

But actually, you can use the [`Show`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.show?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) method instead to show Form B in a non-blocking way.

This effectively lets you have two forms at the same time, even though they are on the same thread.

Additionally, [`Show`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.show?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) has an overload to take an `IWin32Window` as an owner (and the `Form` class does implement `IWin32Window`)

So, you can actually show Form B the following way:

```
FB.Show(this);
```

Even if cross-threading wasn't a problem, it wouldn't have worked because you called `ShowDialog` without an owner passed as a parametter, which is why you get a crash when trying to use `this.Owner` in Form B, since it has default value `null`.

But as you mentionned in your comments, `FB.ShowDialog(this);` crashes because Form A isn't on the same thread as Form B.

Which is why using [`Show`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.show?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) is the best solution here to avoid overcomplicating your code.

Here is the full code I came up with:

```
public partial class FormA : Form
{
    FormB FB = new FormB();

    public Button A1;
    public FormA()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        A1 = new Button();
        A1.Click += new EventHandler(A1Click);
        this.Controls.Add(this.A1);

        FB.Show(this);
    }

    void A1Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FB.B1Text("B1");
    }

    public void A1Text(string text1)
    {
        this.A1.Text = text1;
    }
}

public partial class FormB : Form
{
    public Button B1;
    public FormB()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        B1 = new Button();
        B1.Click += new EventHandler(B1Click);
        this.Controls.Add(this.B1);
    }

    void B1Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormA FA = (FormA)this.Owner;
        FA.A1Text("A1");
    }

    public void B1Text(string text1)
    {
        this.B1.Text = text1;
    }
}
```

However, do note that having both forms on the same thread means that when one form is blocked due to some work it is doing, it'll also block the other form.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the owner. In all operating systems, GUIs work by exchanging messages with the windowing system. Only the thread that runs the message pump can modify the UI. Otherwise you'd end up with half-drawn forms on top of each other. The second form can't run without starting another message pump.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Assigning the owner itself isn't responsible for the issue on paper, but check the .NET reference source that I linked: the Owner properties calls a method on the newly assigned Form, which is done on Form B's thread here since this is where the ``ShowDialog`` function is called, resulting in an exception. Hence my workaround here, by having the owner put on a separate attribute that does not have this problem, therefore answering OP's question. And in any case, I have given a non-multithreading answer as well to just avoid this issue entirely.

Comment: If you believe that my answer is wrong, then test the code I have embedded. I have tested it and it works and respects OP's constraints.

Comment: @RedStoneMatt Thanks! Your multithreading solution works well for my purpose. I'll try to implement it to my complete codes. And sorry for not being able to vote your answer. It seems my former stupid questions gives me a low reputation for voting.

Comment: @RedStoneMatt The solution without multithreading may also be OK for me, if the 2nd form is not always in front of the 1st. I had tried '.show' and met this problem but didn't describe it in the question. I want the active form on top. Maybe it can be solved easily, then this simpler solution is better. And you reminded me the other reason that I use multithreading forms. When I developed my last GUI, I had one form blocked by the other form as you mentioned, but I didn't remember the detail.

Comment: @reko yes, that is the point of using ``Show``: it displays the new form without blocking the previous one. The active form is then always on top. No need to upvote my answer, it if achieved the correct results for you then just mark it as correct (click the checkmark under the votes count).

Comment: @RedStoneMatt Done. I didn't notice this button! I tried your non-multithreading solution and FormB is always in front of FormA. Mathew said it was because Form.Show(this) passed 'this'. I deleted 'this' and then whichever is active is on top. But then I can't access FormA from FormB again! Still your first solution work well with my complete codes.